# Error in mapping interval data type to string in netezza

Tags: hive, sqoop, netezza

I am trying to import a table from Netezza to Hive, with one of the column type as INTERVAL DAY in Netezza.

Table Structure in Netezza:

```
       CREATE TABLE DEMO (id INT PRIMARY KEY, bday INTERVAL DAY);
```

I am using sqoop to import the table along with its data in hive, As hive does not have support for INTERVAL data type, So while importing I am mapping INTERVAL data type to STRING.

Here is the command I am using to import:

```
    $SQOOP_HOME/bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:netezza://192.168.145.24:5480/health_care --table DEMO  --username admin --password password --hive-import --map-column-hive ID=INT,BDAY=STRING --m 4
```

While running the above command I am facing below error:

> 15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 101
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 101
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 101
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 101 for column BDAY
>       15/02/04 20:44:38 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseNullVal(ClassWriter.java:1322)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseColumn(ClassWriter.java:1347)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter._generateParser(ClassWriter.java:1466)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateParser(ClassWriter.java:1434)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generateClassForColumns(ClassWriter.java:1860)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1672)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>         at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue and i solved my issue.

simple logic when we are importing any data to hive first sqoop will import into hdfs and then it will move the data into hive table. so we have to map both hdfs and hive also. but not for all datatypes,

--map-column-java BDAY=String --map-column-hive BDAY=string.

Comment: Why is it not required for all data types then?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a error in sqoop, not in Netezza. In Netezza, you need to use `to_char(interval, text)` to convert an interval to string. For example

```
to_char(interval '15h 2m 12s', 'HH24:MI:SS')
```